# Snakemake: Running hybrid workflows

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I was wondering if there is any way to configure snakemake so that certain rules can be run locally while others are run on an cluster.

For example, suppose I had rule A, which is lightweight, and rule B, which is more computationally expensive. Rule B requires the output of rule A. Is there any way for me to run rule A on a local computer and rule B be submitted as a job via SLURM?

EDIT:
I should have read the documentation more thoroughly. What I said above can be accomplished using localrules.

As a modification to the above question, can I run one rule on a cluster and one rule on the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

A probably cluncky solution is to use `ssh` to execute commands on the remote host. I don't use the cloud but I assume you can ssh there or do something equivalent. So something like:

```
rule one:
    input:
        'data.txt',
    output:
        'results.txt',
    shell:
        r"""
        rsync -arvP {input} me@123.123.123:~/
        ssh me@123.123.123 "sort {input} > {output}"
        rsync -arvP me@123.123.123:~/{output} ./ 
        """
```

Comment: I would really prefer to separate the pipeline/analysis from the underlying system that executes it. I guess snakemake does not have that functionality built yet so I suppose I will have to wait. Thank you for your suggestion though!